# The requested resource is not available error while calling Java service through curl command

Tags: java, curl, jboss

We have a monitoring application which executes `curl` command written in an `Excel` file every 5min. The `curl` command calls a service which is deployed in `JBOSS-eap-6.1 server`. the application is working fine but it gives intermittent error while executing the curl command. Below is the error message :

```
"JBWEB000124- The requested resource is not available.".
```

However, when we manually try to execute same `curl`, it works fine. also, in the subsequent run the issue doesn't appear. Its difficult to reproduce the issue as it comes only 1 out of 1000 runs. Can someone help to find the root cause of this issue.

Comment: The answer might be lurking in your server-side logs.

Comment: Exactly, read your server logs for the time when you got the error in the client side.